# Can't connect remotely to PostGIS docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

I've created a PostGIS docker container with the following code:

```
docker run --name=h4d -d -e POSTGRES_USER=h4d_user -e POSTGRES_PASS=password -e POSTGRES_DBNAME=gis -e ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0 -p 5432:5432 -v h4d_data:/var/lib/postgresql --restart=always kartoza/postgis:latest
```

I can connect to the docker from my localhost, but I can't from another terminal. The error message says "could not connect to server: Connextion timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I'm not sure if maybe I must edit some firewall settings or something else. I'm working on Windows 10

Comment: No I didn't, I'm not sure how to edit both files inside a docker container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help ..

Go to the `postgresql.conf` and change the parameter of `listen_addresses` to the ip address you wish or just place `*` for all ips, e.g:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

In the [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file you also have to add which ips and users may access a certain database, e.g.

```
host my_db my_user 128.176.1.1 md5
```

In an Ubuntu machine these files are normally found at: `/etc/postgresql/10/main`

Comment: @FranMartinRivas the error message from the database, and `ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0` is rather at the container. Normally when a database server isn't reached, e.g. due to a firewall, the connection hangs and eventually gets a time out. The instructions I posted are to enable postgres to accept connections from remote servers, since it is **not** set by default.